# Java SOAP Digital Signature WSS4J

Tags: java, soap, webserver, digital-signature, wss4j

I am working on the assignment where I need to consume the Web Service by signing it digitally. I have generated Web Service client using JAX-WS. For signing the soap request I have implemented the SOAP Handler which will sign the envelope using APACHE wss4j library before posting it to the server. I have .pfx file which I am loading into keystore and using for signing purpose.

This all is working fine when I run this code from eclipse and getting the proper response from the server.

The problem is that I have included the same code in my web application and trying to send request from there but somehow the signature is not verified at the server end and getting response soap:Server 75275

My question is, will wss4j work for signing the soap request in web server? If no, then what another way I can try to resolve this issue. Any direction to the solution will be highly appreciated.

Code

```
Document doc = soapEnv.getOwnerDocument();

            WSSecSignature builder = new WSSecSignature();

            WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp();

            WSSecUsernameToken usernametoken = new WSSecUsernameToken();
            usernametoken.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
            usernametoken.setUserInfo(SOAP_USER, SOAP_USER_PASS);
            usernametoken.addNonce();
            usernametoken.addCreated();

            WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();
            // secHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);
            secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

            usernametoken.build(doc, secHeader);
            timestamp.build(doc, secHeader);

            builder.setUserInfo(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD);
            builder.setX509Certificate(cert);
            builder.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
            builder.setSignatureAlgorithm(WSConstants.RSA_SHA1);
            builder.setSigCanonicalization(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
            builder.setDigestAlgo(WSConstants.SHA1);
            builder.setUseSingleCertificate(true);
            builder.appendBSTElementToHeader(secHeader);

            // Set message parts to sign
            List<WSEncryptionPart> parts = new ArrayList<WSEncryptionPart>();
            WSEncryptionPart bodyPart1 = new WSEncryptionPart("Body", WSConstants.URI_SOAP11_ENV, "Content");
            bodyPart1.setElement(soapBody);
            parts.add(bodyPart1);
            builder.setParts(parts);

            // Set keystore and sign the document
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("org.apache.wss4j.crypto.provider",
                    "class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");

            Merlin crypto = (Merlin) CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties);
            crypto.setKeyStore(store);

            doc = builder.build(doc, crypto, secHeader);

            soapMsg.saveChanges();
```

// code to get cert and store

```
// code to get cert and keystore
private boolean getX509Certificate() {
    String keyAlias = "";
    try {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE); //.pfx file
        this.store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        store.load(stream, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        Enumeration<String> aliases = store.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();
            if (store.getCertificate(alias).getType().equals("X.509")) {
                keyAlias = alias;
            }
        }
        this.cert = (X509Certificate) store.getCertificate(keyAlias);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

//exception

> soap:Server.75275
>   Response Value:soap:Server.75275
>   2018-05-11 18:56:17,977 ERROR [WebService](WFA:132301310 - 152335722 Associate:349730687 IE=349730685) Exception javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 
>   2018-05-11 18:56:17,978 ERROR [WebService](WFA:132301310 - 152335722 Associate:349730687 IE=349730685) [org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:684)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
>    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
>    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy256.synchronousSendAndReceive(Unknown Source)

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: A web server is a container to run the code. Your code should work both in Eclipse and the server. `soap:Server 75275` does not mean nothing. Post the full soap message response and the code you are using so people could analyze it. Also check the soap messages sent in both scenarios to look for differences

Comment: Thanks, @pedrofb for looking into this. I have updated the question with code snippet and stack trace. let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Depending on the application server you use, XML support libraries can be different and get unexpected results in the construction of the SOAP message. I suggest you capture the SOAP message that is sent in both cases to detect the differences.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have compared the two messages which are "valid" and "Invalid". The only difference I could see is the Signature value. Excuse my limited knowledge here but the signature length for valid one is 352 characters while it is 344 characters in Invalid. The rest of the message and tags are matching so not sure where it is making difference.

Comment: make sure you use the same version of the libraries in the development environment as in the deployment. Some application servers ¨ (for example, weblogic) include their own XML signature libraries. In this case you will have to force to use yours